# Does Back To The Future ever directly (visually) contradict itself?

Tags: back-to-the-future

This question is inspired by my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244852/what-happened-to-marty-in-the-altered-timeline-created-by-his-original-trip-to-1).

In that answer, I speculate that there is only ever a single timeline, and thus, a single Marty. In other words, if we could "freeze" the camera at the beginning of BTTF1 and pan it around, just before Marty goes to 1955, we should see at least two things:

1. Marty coming down the hill towards Doc.
2. The sign change to Lone Pine Mall.

Marty from the beginning of the movie would be oblivious to this as he's busy dealing with terrorists. And it might cause a paradox if he did.

There are a few times we see the same events from different points of view. A non-inclusive list being:

1. Marty going to 1955.
2. Marty and Loraine talking in the car.
3. George punching Biff.
4. The DeLorean going back to 1985.
5. Marty singing Johnny B Goode.
6. Marty, George and Loraine's conversation outside the dance (when future Marty is talking to Biff and gets smacked in the face by other Marty).

My instinct is that the first time we see these scenes, they do not directly contradict that the later scene *could* be occurring at the same time off-camera (and least mostly), and the producers intended it this way. But I'm curious as to if there are direct, visual holes in this "illusion".

In fact, that would seem to support the reason paradoxes are such a big deal in BTTF - if there was simply multiple timelines, you just meet yourself in an alternate timeline. Ergo, the timeline can be *changed* but not *contradicted*.

Comment: Your reasoning here doesn't make any sense to me. Why would the "Twin Pines Mall" sign change at the _beginning_ of the first film?

Comment: The sign would have changed at 1:24am - exactly when 1955 Marty showed up. It makes sense if you consider that BTTF has only a single timeline, and thus, only one of any given time on that timeline. Had Marty stuck to Doc's original plan, he would have arrived at 1:34am - which is when the sign would have changed instead. Because he returned early, there's a brief window original Marty could have become aware of the changes (likely creating a paradox). Sort of like in Harry Potter 3 where we see the events time traveling Harry and Hermione are causing before we actually see them travel back.

Comment: And yes I realize that creates its own issue - why does everyone else's memories (including Docs) get updated, but Marty's doesn't? We might imagine it was because Marty specifically was the Time Traveler. In any case, it's tangential to this question.

Comment: I agree that there's only one reality in BTTF, which overwrites itself whenever the timeline is altered. But why would the Mall sign change near the beginning of the film, rather than near the end?

Comment: I think there's a lot of ambiguity over how time travelers get updated.   But in a cosmic sense there's only one timeline that gets rewritten as necessary.   Now there's no reason Marty bttf2 in 1955 could rewrite significantly bttf1 and deal with consequences.   But obviously they did as much as possible to not disrupt bttf1 in bttf2.  Time travel can be chaotic butterfly curve instead if a loop sometimes - though bttf trys to keep it simple.

Comment: Tronman you are quite wrong here.  There is only one timeline in bttf but it does get rewritten and updated. If the timeline was fixed and self consistent then we would see a running Marty at the beginning of the film. Instead we see small changed details like twin pine becoming lone pine at the END of the film. Doc was not wearing a bullet proof vest the first time but wore it concealed the 2nd time to maintain consistency.  The pine sign would have had plenty of time to update so I would not expect it to change the instant 1955 Marty arrived.  That change would have already propagated.

Comment: From what we see in BTTF, the "ripple effect" that overwrites the timeline is is always preceded by the event that caused that ripple in the first place. For example, 1985-A, where Biff is married to Lorraine, didn't exist until after Old Biff had gone back to 1955 to give the almanac to Young Biff. By that same token, Lone Pine Mall cannot exist before Marty has gone back to 1955 and made the changes that he did in the first film.

Comment: To be clear, the intended point of the question is to establish whether or not there exists direct, visual evidence that the later events are not occurring at the same time we initially view the events. A direct, answerable question regardless of if we "believe" the later events are occurring (or not).

Comment: I think you are dealing with a bit of a false premise in the question itself.  I think there are many things to discuss but that is not the nature of the site. But the bulk of bttf2 may be the biggest paradox.  If they go to the future and meet their old selves the universe has obviously assumed they will go back to 1985 as the highest probability event.  A universe that was more strict but with updating would note Marty disappeared in 1985 but let him return.  A self consistent timeline would only allow 1985 Marty to see 2015 Marty if destiny forced Marty to go back - which is not bttf

Comment: The tough bit is you have to stick to the time-travel rules of the movie. Like when the picture doesn't instantly change to reflect timeline changes(or even disappear from existence, as it _should_ do). Even the writer aknowledged this makes no sense. But, still, it's a part of the temporal physics of the movie.

Comment: I hadn't intended it as a discussion question. It was more a question of cinematography and if the producers staged their scenes in such a way that they are self-consistent. I see your point though. It's funny - in 30 years of watching and rewatching BTTF I've never considered it as anything other than the "future" events are intended to be occurring simultaneously with the "current" events, just off camera. It just felt obvious to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several side by side comparisons on youtube.

From what I can see there are no major discrepancies. In the mall scene, Doc falls a little differently when shot (he kind of flings backwards at the start of the film, but kneels and falls over at the end). The Libyan's van at one point seems closer to Doc's van in one timeline than the other.
In the dance scene, Marvin Berry makes the 'phone call noticeably later in one timeline. Marty seems a little less energetic playing Johnny B Goode.

Certainly nothing in universe seems intended to be different; it's notable that we never see the Mall sign after the time (future) Marty returns, and don't get a good look under Doc's coat to see if he has the bullet proof vest already or not at the start of the movie. Indeed, it seems as if the movies takes pains to make the events as close to each other as possible.

Comment: This may be of interest to readers.. 
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle switching franchises if one was really aggressive a good hearted time traveler good replace Edith Keeler with a decoy and keep the timeline on track.  Also the plot of Millennium where disaster victims get switched with decoys to repopulate the future but keep history consistent.